# Toolbar not docking to bottom in iPhone 5 or greater

Tags: xcode, constraints, xcode8

I have a toolbar that for some reason is not docking to the bottom.  In the view, I tried setting "Layout Margins" to "Explicit" and then setting the left, bottom and right margins to Zero but it still floats close to the bottom but I need it to be docked at the bottom for all devices.  It was fine in iPhone 4 but after Xcode update to 8.2.1 and testing it on iPhone 5, it no longer docks to the bottom.

Here is a picture of what is happening.

[image]

Please do not downvote the question, if you need additional information, just write a comment and I will supply the requested information.

**Update #1**

Here are the settings:

[image]

Comment: Judging from the screenshot you posted, it looks like you are using navigation controller which already has a built in toolbar. Have you tried setting `isToolbarHidden = false` on the instance of your navigation controller?

Comment: Thanks Michael, I added a screenshot of the current settings.  I am not sure if it is using the built in toolbar.

Comment: If you added one manually, then no. To enable included toolbar, select your `NavigationController` on the left (the yellow circle that says `Navigation Controller`), then navigate to `Attributes Inspector` and make sure to check `Show Toolbar` checkbox...

Comment: Michael, you are correct!  "Shows Toolbar" is not checked.  I took over this code.  I am not sure why they developed their own toolbar.  I have lots of views that use this toolbar.  I am not sure what would be involved in converting all views to use the built-in toolbar.